# Docker kill an infinite process in a container after X amount of time

Tags: bash, shell, docker, infinite-loop, infinite

I am using the code found in this docker [issue](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/1905) to basically start a container run a process within 20 seconds and if the process **completes** / **does not complete** / **fails to execute** / **times out** the container is killed regardless.

The code I am using currently is this:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

to=$1
shift

cont=$(docker run -d "$@")
code=$(timeout "$to" docker wait "$cont" || true)
docker kill $cont &> /dev/null
echo -n 'status: '
if [ -z "$code" ]; then
    echo timeout
else
    echo exited: $code
fi

echo output:
# pipe to sed simply for pretty nice indentation
docker logs $cont | sed 's/^/\t/'

docker rm $cont &> /dev/null
```

Which is almost perfect however if you run an infinite process (for example this python infinite loop):

```
while True:
    print "inifinte loop"
```

The whole system jams up and the app crashes, after reading around a bit I think it has something to do with the **STDOUT Buffer** but I have absolutely no idea what that means?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you have is with a process that is writing massive amounts of data to stdout.
These messages get **logged into a file which grows infinitely**.
Have a look at (depending on your system's location for log files):

```
sudo find /var/lib/docker/containers/ -name '*.log' -ls
```

You can remove old log files if they are of no interest.
One possibility is to start your `docker run -d` daemon
under a ulimit restriction on the max size a file can be.
Add to the start of your script, for example:

```
ulimit -f 20000 -c 0
```

This limits file sizes to 20000*1024 bytes, and disables core file dumps, which you expect
to get from infinite loops where writes are forced to fail.

Comment: Hey I cannot figure out where to add the above code to my code, any ideas?

Comment: Add the `ulimit` after the `set -e` in your script. You may need to increase the limit a lot as docker probably needs to use big files for other things than logs.

Comment: Cheers had to actually add to a script ran in the docker VM but it worked just like it should! thank you

Answer (score 0):

Please add & at the end of 
cont=$(docker run -d "$@")&

It will run the process in background.

I don't know dockers but if it still fail to stop you may also add just after this line the following :

mypid=$!
sleep 20 && kill $mypid

Regards

Comment: Running as a background process made it far worse, and the other line did not work, Docker is micro virtual machines, I am assuming the answer is going to be quite specialized, but thank you for trying.

Comment: Sorry, yes it was the purpose to run the process in background. Otherwise you are going to wait your loop is completed before launching the next instruction. I wanted to press returned but it seems that my pad doesn't work well. There are 2 commands : mypid=$! ; then press return ^^ and sleep 20 && kill $mypid It shall kill your virtual machine. It may be the cleaner way. I'll check if I can find any doc on this and post a better answer if I found one